How is this an 'offtopic' question? Can this please be reopened?
How bad would near constant dreary/gloomy/stormy weather on our or an Earthlike world be for us and the environment?
So my question was closed for supposedly being offtopic. This is obviously not the case, and this is a WB question. Someone said because it was too wide of a scope, even though we literally build worlds, lol!!! The only somewhat valid reason to close it would be because it is asking multiple questions, but tbf the question I had umbrellas them. But yeah, judging by upvotes, I did nothing wrong here.
Can my question be reopened please?

Stack Exchange, Stack moderators and Stack users have patiently explained to new users over and over for years and years... popularity does not abrogate the rules. Upvotes mean nothing when it comes to question closure. Edit your post to conform to the rules as stated in the [help] and your question will be reopened.

Why did you vtc close it for being off topic? I thought you said it is too broad? @JBH

My comment was pretty clear. I voted "Not About Worldbuilding per the [Help]" for being too broad (violates the Book Rule, see [help/dont-ask]). I even explained what it specifically means.

Ah. You might be reacting to the closed question notice. The first line reads, "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers." This isn't an explanation, it's just a statement of fact. The question was closed as "off-topic," which is SE's general phrase meaning "the question is inappropriate for Stack Exchange." The reason is given in the next line, "This question does not appear to be about worldbuilding, within the scope defined in the help center." However, while that was the reason I voted to close, it's not necessarily the reason everybody gave. (*Cont.*)

Too broad does not equal not worldbuilding. @JBH

... Stack Exchange only lists the most-voted reason. Had three people voted to close as "Needs More Focus," then that reason would have been listed despite my having chosen "Not About Worldbuilding within the scope defined in the Help Center."

You're not listening Conan. It doesn't matter if you believe you wrote a legitimate worldbuilding question - you broke Stack Exchange's rules. You have only two choices. (1) Edit your question to conform with the rules or (2) live with the closure.

It 100% is ontopic, not an opinion nor me being semantic. So anyways... how would I fix it without confusing new and current answerers? Should I post like a handful of questions about it? @JBH

You're still not listening Conan. Let's try it this way, when you see the line "Closed. This question is off-topic." what you need to think in your head is this, "This question is off-topic because it has been closed." The reason your question was closed was given on the second line. Your question was not closed because we think it isn't a worldbuilding question. It was closed because it doesn't follow the rules found in the [help].

No suggestions on how to fix it? @JBH

My question is how would this affect the world? Would plants all die off? How would humans be directly affected by this? And the animals also? Would it still be really bad if it was, say, only the USA? That's one general question that violates the Book Rule (way too broad) and four more questions when you are allowed to ask only one. So long as you continue to ask how your conditions will affect everything on the planet, we'll keep it closed. Even if you asked how it would only affect humans, that violates the Book Rule as it includes everything from (*Continued*)

... fashion to respiratory ailments to skin problems to hair care to transportation to water management to sewers to a thousand other things. Too broad! To make matters worse, you appear to have done no research into populated areas of the Earth that live in reasonably similar conditions (very high rainwater, very low number of sunny days) to see how they have already answered your question. Research is required (see [ask]) and its lack is the factual reason for down voting.

Why do you guys keep deleting comments? This is Meta.

@ConanHighwoods -- Some comments were a) not pertinent to this question (they were about a separate but related Q&A site) or b) unhelpful for your understanding of what the issues are (providing contrary or incorrect information).

My Penny Hapenny

I read your questions in Main and here in Meta. I read the responses and all the comments. More importantly, I read everything between the lines.

Your query wasn't closed because it's "off topic". That verbiage is SE boilerplate alerting everyone that the question is off topic for a certain reason. The reason your query was closed is because it does not meet some criterion in the Help Center. Clicking on that link would lead you to helpful information such as what kinds of questions are not a good fit for WB.SE. There is also a helpful link that delves into what makes for a good question.
You did in fact question the reasoning for the VTC given by at least other member. This person explained to you very clearly the whys and wherefores. I think there may have been some misunderstanding on your part. JBH wasn't saying that your query was problematic because it's "for a book". Rather, the "book rule" alludes to the fact that the question you asked could literally be answered with a book length answer. In fact, we actually several whole sciences devoted to just this topic, from meteorology to climate sciences. We also have whole political ideologies and party policies that are based on just this question.
Your question was closed simply because the answers could fill a small library.
You also brought up, here in your Meta question, another totally valid reason for closure. You admit yourself that you were asking too many questions. It is in fact SE policy that you shall ask only one question. There are no weasel words here and this is not a "somewhat valid" reason. Your question can, and should, remain validly closed until you fix the problems it's got rather than complain that someone else is pointing out the problems and alerting you to them.

Your query can indeed be reopened --- and it is largely up to you when and how this gets done. I would suggest that a good first step would be to take a moment to cool off. You got into a bit of a snit with JBH in your original question. It happens. You're not the first person to get all defensive about your question, and you won't be the last. Do know this: JBH is one of the most helpful and knowledgeable members this forum has. He did not VTC your question out of spite or whim.
Essentially, in order to get your question reopened, I would reccomend the following:

Read the Help Center;

Take the Tour;

Find out what Worldbuilding is all about.

Reread your own query as if someone else had written it and you were a community moderator: look for the problems, poke holes in it. Look for key phrases like "how good or bad would X be..." and "how would X affect Y...". Unqualified how questions are by nature too broad. They lead to "book rule" violations. Also look out for a lack of constraints: this is not us being petty, but the simple expectation of Stack Exchange is that you shall write a narrowly focused question. Also be on the look out for a question that lacks worldbuilding context. Questions that seek real world information but fail to synthesise that within the context of the fictional world are not a good fit for this forum. Those questions should be asked elsewhere on SE!

Taking these things into consideration, objectively evaluate your own question and look for places where it can be improved. You've got a good foundation! A few edits here and there will turn this into a useful worldbuilding question for real!

Take advantage of the Sandbox! It was literally designed to help you write a good worldbuilding question that is far less likely to be closed!



The question was closed because and I quote "This question does not appear to be about worldbuilding, within the scope defined in the help center.". Your primary question, quoting again, was "how would this affect the world?" This requires the answerer to first catalogue the world, then address it, in totality, in detail. In response to that please let me gently suggest that we are not here to write an alternative version of the Encyclopedia Britannica, for anyone, ever. If you want it reopened you'll need to edit it into a far more focused piece asking a specific question about one issue, and do it without making the current answer(s) void or the edit will not stand.

Maybe I can narrow it down to just a country or continent?

@ConanHighwoods You may get away with one continent or country and one industry or sector, "how would this effect farming in North America?" as an example, or "how would Spanish road construction methods need to change to cope with this scenario?", you might still get told that it's opinion based but you'd be a lot closer to a properly answerable question.

@ConanHighwoods one area is still too large. "how would having magical gunpowder influence the reunification of China in the warring states period" is not answerable because to answer it, you'd need to define all the magical gunpowder stick in a 50k words essay first.

@ConanHighwoods No, narrowing it down to a single country or continent will not suffice. There's too much involved. Roads, utilities, taxation, industry, agriculture, medical, distribution... all the way down to how my little sister plays in the back yard. You're asking for a volume of information that literally exceeds what you can find via Google searches on a service that's designed to provide answers that are more-or-less one page long.

So no point in editing it then? @JBH

@ConanHighwoods Why is this so difficult? We want you to edit the question to conform with the rules. (a) [tour] (b) [help/on-topic] (c) [help/dont-ask] (d) [ask] + avoiding the closure reasons given in the vote-to-close panel.

You have been already explained in the comment what are the problems with your question, and you have dismissed them as "problems the commenter is making".
Why don't you try fixing them, instead?
Ask 1 worldbuilding question with a scope narrow enough to not require writing a book to be answered.

It was closed for being offtopic though, which it is not. Regarding it being too broad. I mean several users already gave non essay length answers, so it seems to be at least passable.

How so? Should I just ask how it would effect nature?

@ConanHighwoods It was not closed for being off-topic. Stop looking at the first line, which is nothing more than a statement that the question has been closed. Look at the second line. Your question was closed for not following the rules found in the [help].

What are you going to do with a library-sized pile of information?
As of the date of this answer, there remain the same two problems that have always existed with your question.

You are asking more than one question. It doesn't matter how related the questions are, you are required to ask only one. Sometimes, sometimes, with younger users we give a little leeway and let them ask a supporting, secondary question — but you've been a member of WB.SE for more than three years now. You're no longer allowed leeway. One question. Only one question.

The Rule: From the Vote to Close panel we read...

Needs More Focus This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

There are obviously multiple ways to interpret this, but the most common is question marks, commas, and conjunctions.

"How does X affect A?" is one question.
"How does X affect A? How does it affect B?" are two questions.
"How does X affect A and B?" is a single sentence containing two questions.
"How does X affect A, B and C?" is a single sentence containing three questions. Etc.

The next most common way to interpret this is ambiguity, although that's much less common. "How does my climate affect the world?" can be legitimately closed as Needs More Focus because the question is so ambiguous (on a service that expects specificity, such as "how does overwatering affect my dracaena trifasciata?") that it's considered unfocused.

You are asking for a library-sized volume of information. How climate affects an entire world is asking for an entire library of information on a service that expects answers to be, on average, one page long. You're asking for everything because there's nothing about your question that helps us narrow down the answer. Do you really want to know how your conditions would affect how my little sister plays outside?

The Rule: From the Help Center we read...

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

In your case, you're asking for a lot more than just one book worth of information. Where do we stop? Every plant, every animal, every insect, soil erosion, sociocultural consequences, psychology, philosophy & religion, medical & veterinary, industry/science/education... EVERYTHING is affected by the weather my friend. Stack Exchange users are not allowed to ask questions that would take days to answer (much less years, which is the case here) or that would singly fill up SE's hard drives.
How can you solve these problems?
Here are some suggestions:

Explain to us how you will use the information. That can give us insight into how to suggest scoping your question.
Explain to us how you will judge a best answer.
Explain to us why Google couldn't solve your problem.
Use our Sandbox.
Believe us when we tell you what's wrong.

That last one is, perhaps, the most important. I can't explain why some people simply won't change their question to conform with Stack Exchange's expectations. There are people who won't drive he speed limit, either, so maybe it's as simple as there's a type of person who just hates authority. Beats me. But no matter what you might think, there really is nobody on this service who wants you to stop asking questions. Nobody. Not one.
What we want is for you to follow the rules. That means you need to know the rules, and the rules are found in the Tour, the Vote to Close reasons (in the VTC panel) and the Help Center. If you don't understand them, please ask, we're happy to help! But above all, please believe us when we say there's a problem that you need to fix.

@Antares I voted to close for two reasons: too broad and too many questions. Perhaps you can't count, but the current version of the question asks one ridiculously broad question and four more still too broad questions. If you choose to say that it's one question with an untamed train of thought, then it still violates the Book Rule. You're on day 41. Please spend day 42 actually reading the [help] and choosing to honor the rules Stack Exchange has set. Thanks.

I retracted my comment. Didn't mean to upset you, my apologies for that. Please stop trying to imply I would not have read the pages you linked. Maybe I prioritize the people's side more than the rule's side. There are not only Q&A there are first and foremost people that post them. And also SE acknowledges that to a certain point. Also if you keep counting my days here, this will lead nowhere. -- Apart from that: Genuinely thank you for your relentless efforts to make this a better place and staying in contact with the people.
